# Can Gmail auto-label sent emails based on a filter?

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels

About 90% of emails I send out in Gmail:
1. Need to be labeled
2. Can be labeled based on a simple filter (e.g. specific "To:" address)

Can I automatically apply labels to send emails when sent; based on filter(s)?

*(P.S. I'm aware I can manually assign a label by going to "labels" menu when composing email; as well as filter any unlabeled sent mails and mass-apply the label later. I'm looking for more automated solution).*

Answer (score 2):

I created a filter based only on a `To:` address.

> Matches: to:(nobody@example.com)
>   Do this: Apply label "Testing"

When I sent a simple message to that address, the message ended up with the "Testing" label. The only downside would seem to be that the message is automatically marked as "read", I expect because it's a sent message.

So the answer would seem to be **Yes**, you can create filters that act on messages as you send them.

Comment: I don't particularly mind that downside, i'll test this and accept if it works for me. Thanks!

Comment: The trouble with this is that applying labels isn't really what I am after.  Google seems to overload the "folder" concept onto labels, and "folders" is why I want labels.  It is of no value to me to have labeled emails in my sent "folder".  I want them to appear under the label I've tagged them with.